# How to catch every change in the zoom level of MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit

I looked up in Apple documentation and saw how set zoom level, but couldn't see the method in event of user zooms in and/or out of the map.

I need to catch all this events for each zoom level changes. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MKMapView` delegate methods

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Or if you want to do some work before map adjust new region simply use the following

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```